# Triple Boot with Windows 7, Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, multi-boot

currently I have dual boot with 2 windows 7. (dont ask why, long story, I need them for each with different settings involving Audio Recording)

I am very keen to install the new Ubuntu and get into a new OS, out of interest but I don't want to mess with my current 2 windows installations?

If I install Ubuntu, will this simply add to my list of OS boot options when you set it, like I did when I install my 2nd Windows 7

Any comments or help would be great?
Thanks
Bill

Comment: `"I need them for each with different settings involving audio recording"`  -- I'd put together a script to transform between the two modes

Answer (score 2):

It's much better to use a virtualizer like VirtualBox than dual and triple-booting, IMHO. I personally use it to run two guests (Ubuntu and Windows XP) on my host (Windows XP). The second Windows XP is a "clean host" to test development products - and using VirtualBox'es snapshots it's very easy to recover - a flexibility you won't get with a triple boot.

Comment: I don't know much about this, what advantages would you say this has? Does this mean running an OS on top of an OS?

Answer (score 1):

> If I install Ubuntu, will this simply
>   add to my list of OS boot options when
>   you set it, like I did when I install
>   my 2nd Windows 7 ?

Yes, that's correct.